# Please add `unwatch tag` to obsolete/unused tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Tags can be deleted automatically due to lack of questions/activity or due to [tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

When a tag doesn't exist, its page does not display the *Unwatch tag* and *Ignore tag* buttons, despite the tag being watched.

For instance, compare the following two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I am aware that tags can be removed from the watched list using the **edit** button. However, from my point of view it would be more self-consistent and easy to use to show the `Unwatch tag` button in both cases.

Would it be possible to change the website to display the `Unwatch tag` button in both cases?

Comment: Aren't tags removed from watch lists when they're deleted by the system?

Comment: @TylerH I was going through my watch list and I deleted more than one tag manually (e.g. `[linear]`, `[fzn2smt]`).